# How to fix a TypeError in python

Tags: python, typeerror

The problem is, whenever I try to run the code it always tells me:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

As you can see in the code, I have already tried to add int() around my bank / wallet amounts.

```
with open("accounts/" + username + ".json") as file:
    json_file = json.load(file)
    money = json_file['money']
    bank = int(money['bank'])
    wallet = int(money['wallet'])
    if wallet >= deposit_amount:
        new_bank = bank + deposit_amount
        new_wallet = wallet - deposit_amount
        money['bank'] = new_bank
        json_file['wallet'] = new_wallet
        dump_file = open("accounts/" + username + ".json", 'w')
        json.dump(json_file, dump_file)
    else:
        print("You do not have enough money for that!")


File "C:/Users/riley/PycharmProjects/BankManager/main.py", line 20, in <module> startup()
File "C:/Users/riley/PycharmProjects/BankManager/main.py", line 12, in startup login()
File "C:\Users\riley\PycharmProjects\BankManager\handlers\AccountHandler.py", line 16, in login set_panel(username)
File "C:\Users\riley\PycharmProjects\BankManager\handlers\PanelHandler.py", line 9, in set_panel start_panel(username)
File "C:\Users\riley\PycharmProjects\BankManager\panels\user.py", line 29, in start_panel bank = int(money['bank'])
```

I am making a Money System in python so I can later implement this into a Discord Bot. I am attempting to make a deposit command where if you say 'deposit' it will ask you how much you want to deposit and go from there.

Comment: What's the content of the JSON file like?

Comment: Hi Riley, can you please include the complete `Traceback` as you got, so we can identify the exact line where the error is occurring.  Also, it would be useful to include the value assigned to `json_file`, and correction to the indentation is also useful.

Comment: comment out  most of the code below conversions, try print `bank` and `wallet` and see if the output is actually int.

Comment: I commented out all the code below the converstions and am still getting the error when I try to print them.

Answer (score 0):

I think jason_file is a dictionary of list. Something like:

jason_file = {'money':[some list], .... so on}

So, the result of `money = json_file['money']` would be:

money = [some list]

As you can see, money here is a list. It won't accept 'bank' as index.  Your type casting to int by `int(money['bank'])` does not matter.

Can you please `print(money[0])` to check if it indeed is a list? You may also check if jason_load is dictionary of lists?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that `money['bank']` is not a valid operation because `money` is a list (and not a `dict`). Therefore, you can only access its elements through numerical index (`0`, `1`, `2`, ...) and not through keys (`'bank'`, `'wallet'`, etc.)

From the incomplete snippet you provided (**please provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**) I assume that you want your example to be close to the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_string = '{"money": {"bank": "a bank", "wallet": 1234.56}}'
>>> json_data = json.loads(json_string)
>>> json_data
{"money": {"bank": "a bank", "wallet": 1234.56}}
>>> type(json_data['money'])
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(json_data['money']['wallet'])
<class 'float'>
```

As you can see, [the `json` module loads the JSON type properly](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) and leaves us with Python types. You don't need to cast the values (unless there are enclosed in a string such as `...{"wallet": "1234.56"}...`).

Double check what your `json_file` contains, print its content or at least the type of the money element `print(type(json_file['money']))`.